# Breaking out of an inner loop doesn't terminate the loops

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The code is a four-character password generator. I have an if/else break system setup, but I can't figure out why it isn't working. The loop generates past the limit until it exhausts all options, which I'm having a hard time properly debugging. I'm very new to anything other than javascript and HTML, so any help would be useful. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()  {
  char char1;
  char char2;
  char char3;
  char char4;
  int numPasswordsGenerated = 0;

  cout << "Password Generator:" << endl;

  /* Generates four-character passwords (excludin digits) by exhausting all character
     options between '!' and '~' starting with the fourth character. Once the fourth 
     character exhausts all options, the third character increases by the next character 
     in the binary lineup, then continuing with the fourth character. This process continues 
     until the numPasswordsGenerated integer reaches the desired number, or the password 
     output becomes "~~~~"; whichever comes first.
   */
  char1 = '!';
  while (char1 <= '~')    {
      char2 = '!';
      while (char2 <= '~')    {
          char3 = '!';
          while (char3 <= '~')    {
              char4 = '!';
              while (char4 <= '~') {
                  // cout << char1 << char2 << char3 << char4 << endl;
                  numPasswordsGenerated++;                  //!*FIXME*!
                  cout << numPasswordsGenerated << endl;    //DEBUG DELETE
                  if (numPasswordsGenerated == 10)
                    break;
                    
                  char4++;
                  
              }
          char3++;
              
          }
      char2++;
          
      }
      char1++;
      
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `break` statement only breaks out of the innermost loop, not out of all four. The third loop down then proceeds to the next iteration, `numPasswordsGenerated` becomes 11, and the condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: JavaScript isn't any different to C or C++ in the context of what you're trying to do here. Think how you would debug and resolve this in a language that you do know.

Comment: Would it not be easier to create an array of every valid character and then just use a random function to pick out how many results you want by using a range for loop? If you would like me to expand on what I mean as an answer I can but it doesn't solve your issue. It just provides an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik! I just noticed that after a little more testing. Flew right over my head for a while!

Comment: @TheGrandJ An array would be more efficient (and definitely easier), but I wanted to see if I could do it limiting myself to only loop statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop early, put this in a function and instead of `break` use `return`.

Remember that `break` only kicks out of the loop you're in, not all loops in the scope of the function.

Here's a reworked version with a more flexible input arrangement for the limit using `argv`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void generatePasswords(const size_t limit) {
  char password[5];
  size_t count = 0;

  password[4] = 0;

  password[0] = '!';

  while (password[0] <= '~') {
    password[1] = '!';

    while (password[1] <= '~') {
      password[2] = '!';

      while (password[2] <= '~') {
        password[3] = '!';

        while (password[3] <= '~') {
          password[3]++;

          std::cout << password << std::endl;

          if (++count >= limit) {
            return;
          }
        }

        password[2]++;
      }

      password[1]++;
    }

    password[0]++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Password Generator:" << std::endl;

  generatePasswords(argc >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000);

  return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `char password[5]` instead of a bunch of unrelated characters.